# Open custom keyboard on highlighting webview textfield

Tags: iphone

Can i open custom keyboard instead of default keyboard.

I have an html file containing a textfield,when i start typing default keyboard gets open.

I can change type of keyboard in html file but i dont want to change anything in html file .

Comment: Is this for an iOS app or website?

Answer (score 0):

You calls keyboard by taping on textfield, am i right?
In that case why don't use this code?

```
myField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

By this code you can set different types of your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

@Jaiswal i don't think, you can change the default Appearance style of iPhone, but of course  you can change the format of the keyboard through HTML...

Here's the tutorial http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1721-Default-To-The-Numeric-Email-And-URL-Keyboards-On-The-iPhone.htm

I've tested a lot but apple only allows two keyboard Appearance styles "Default" & "Alert". If you don't want these styles, you can also use your own keyboard simply by taking buttons in another view and scrolling the view up whenever the keyboard is required.

But using a UIWebView, and then making your custom keyboard is not possible(I guess).
If I am wrong or you find any answer, then please post the answer...... :)

And ya.... is think this is a HTML side question not iPhone :)

Comment: I also tried a lot and i also think its not possible thats why i am asking "can i".

Comment: Actually, the keyboard that pops up in your UIWebView, when you click in a textfield, is a custom keyboard.....

Comment: @ AKB8085 how can u say that this is a html side question??

Comment: the logic is... hide the default keyboard for typing, and make your custom keyboard using HTML/CSS(i don't know both these languages) & then scroll your custom keyboard whenever typing is needed....

Comment: bcoz if you use UIWebView in Xcode, then you can't set the UITextField delegates methods for your HTML page's textfields...

Comment: but you have notification of showing and hiding keyboard, web injenction etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27539/discussion-between-k-jaiswal-and-akb8085)